# Drupal 7 - Active menu items does not have active-trail class

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-menu

As mentioned in the title, for some reason, particular menu items that have `active` class do not have `active-trail` class and so do their parents.

Example menu tree when I am currently at page Test2:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first expanded">
        <a href="/test" class="active">Test</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first expanded">
                <a href="/test2" class="active">Test2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is how should it be when I am currently at page Test2:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first expanded active-trail">
        <a href="/test" class="active active-trail">Test</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first expanded active-trail">
                <a href="/test2" class="active active-trail">Test2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that your theme (*or a module*) is overriding the output using one of these hooks and changing the classes:

- [**theme_menu_link**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x)
- [theme_menu_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7.x)
- [template_preprocess_menu_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/template_preprocess_menu_tree/7.x)

I'd recommend starting with checking out the active theme's code.

Or you can just implement `theme_menu_link()` in your theme and override the classes to your liking.

Comment: It seems like the problem is with either Views or i18n modules. Because the problem only appears at translations of pages created by views.